# TCP connection drops first byte

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send a few bytes from Windows 7 to a virtual Ubuntu machine (oracle virtual box) using Java 7 64 bit server vm.
This code runs on Windows

```
ServerSocket server = null;
try {
    server = new ServerSocket(1024);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Socket so = server.accept();
                //Thread.sleep(10);
                OutputStream out = so.getOutputStream();
                out.write(42);
                out.write(43);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                so.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

On Ubuntu I run this

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket so = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        InputStream in = so.getInputStream();
        int b = in.read();
        while(b >= 0) {
            System.out.println(b);
            b = in.read();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the first byte is sometimes dropped. However if I put a Thread.sleep in the server code it alway works correctly? Why is that happening?

Comment: I've tested it on Windows 8 and it works fine.

Comment: You don't need to start a thread on the server side as you have a main thread already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with the client or server programs.

That leaves us grasping at explanations like:

- a bug in the operating system at one end,
- a bug in the virtual networking setup,
- real network errors, or
- ... a hypothetical JVM bug.

None of these explanations can be justified without more information / evidence.

---

The other possibility is that something is interfering with the output going to your console.  Try running the client with output redirected to a file ...

Comment: The problem still occurs when I redirect the output into a file. It only happens when the connection is between the host os (windows 7 in this case) and the os on the virtual machine. A normal localhost connection works fine. So it may be the virtual box networking adapter.